# Charset issue in ajax request using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an ajax request like below:

```
var result;
$.ajax({
      url: command,
      success: function (data) 
         {
           result = jQuery.parseJSON(atob(data));
           alert(JSON.stringify(result));
         },
      async: false,
      contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        });
return result;
```

After call, in alert, there are strange characters instead of `ç`,`ğ`,`ü`,`ö`,`é`,`æ` vs characters.

What is the problem with that?

Comment: What is the character encoding of the HTML page, and what its the character encoding of the file you're reading. (If you say they're both UTF-8 you're most likely wrong; double-check.)

Comment: Results are returned from a web service that connects a database. Charsets are UTF-8

Comment: Sorry, but they are not. Either the database does not return UTF-8, or the data isn't saved there as UTF-8, or the page that returns the results from the Ajax call isn't UTF-8...